# How do I replace the shutoff valve on steel pipe?

Tags: plumbing, valve, replacement, steel, shutoff

Can anyone tell me what I’m working with here? I’d like to replace this gnarly shutoff valve (for a toilet) with one of the newer style quarter turns. It’s an old house, and I *believe* the supply pipe is galvanized steel. It looks to me like a compression valve, but also kind of soldered on the back? How should I go about removing it? And do I need the pipe to be threaded for a new valve? I’m a novice when it comes to the steel pipes.

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: Looks like chrome plated brass valve threaded onto a chrome plated nipple . Nipple could be brass or steel.

Comment: Are the pipes in your house copper? If so you might want to slide the escutcheon plate back and see if you have a set up like this. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93856/replace-chrome-toilet-shut-off-valve

Comment: This just a suggestion, so I'm not posting this as an answer.  I personally hate doing plumbing work...esp. on old plumbing. Something always breaks.  If the valve is working and you are just worried about appearance, I'd just get some steel wool, clean up the oxidation.  Sandpaper might also help.  If then it looks OK, great. If not, you can always get a small brush and paint it, carefully avoiding the stem and where it enters the valve.  ....just a thought, an idea to consider.

Comment: They don't make what you got there anymore. See the link above. Encountering one of these in the wild would make for a bad day and I would quickly run out of swear words. - "I'd like to replace this gnarly shutoff valve" because it still leaks even after tightening the packing nut? Or it's the last possible thing that could be done in a complete renovation to make everything pretty? Otherwise I agree with George: don't open cans of worms for fun.

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE** I'm removing my answer as it has been shown to be incorrect (at least the way I intended it), and this really is a duplicate anyway.